# Firebird pass input parameter to gen_id function

Tags: sql, delphi, stored-procedures, firebird

I want to create stored procedure to get the current id for specific tables i have many tables 
so i don't want to create sp for each one,

I'm trying this way but i fail

```
create procedure
sp_get_id(mytable varchar(128)) returns(id integer)
as
begin
  select gen_id(:mytable, 0) from rdb$database into :id;
  suspend;
end
```

I wonder if there is a way to pass the input param to the gen_id or i must create different sp for each table..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you keep a naming convention so that the generator name can be derived from the table name you could use something similar to this:

```
SET TERM ^;

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SP_GET_ID (
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(128))
RETURNS (
    ID INTEGER)
AS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE STATEMENT 'SELECT GEN_ID(GEN_' || :TABLE_NAME || ', 0) FROM RDB$DATABASE' INTO :ID;
END^

SET TERM ;^
```

Comment: but i guess you forget to add `suspend` at the end

Comment: You only need the `SUSPEND` if you want it to be selectable stored procedure.

Comment: This also can be "anonymous method" - EXECUTE BLOCK without defining a named stored procedure

Comment: You can also add the generator name as a parameter just as you did with the table name.